# What’s the best approach to work with in memory domain objects in Grails?

Tags: memory, grails, dns

I’m working on a Grail’s project that has some Domain objects not persisted on the database. They are managed thru a REST API, so all their CRUD operations will be done with this API instead of the database.

The point is to still be able to use some interesting Grails plug-ins (like searching using Compass).

For instance, the administration the Domain objects Users is going to be managed with the REST API, so when the Users list is displayed a the REST method to retrieve the list of users will be invoked on the remote server. I hope this use case is clear enough :)

I can think on several ways to design that but I'm not sure what’s the best:

- Should I create the Domain Objects in the controller (and delete the
  previous Users stored in memory)?
- It seems it’s possible to define a Domain Class not persistable (with
  mapping I think) but I’m not sure if this is the best approach or
  where to load the data.
- It is better not to model as a Grails the User as Domain object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the REST interactions in a service, and call the service from a controller.  In that case, the service would get the response and create its objects, passing the list back to the controller.  Controllers should just handle incoming requests, invoke application components, and return responses.

It seems you want models to represent the data in the other application, which is a good idea.  Since you don't need GORM, you might want to define them in the 'groovy' folder of your app instead of the domain models folder.  Then I think they will just be objects.

Comment: Thanks for the info, looks nice unless I think I do need GORM for the search plug-in, but I'll give it a try. I guess I can use this approach and use memory as data base instead of a real one, this way the search plug in seems to work fine

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with non-domain objects in `src` folder - though, need to check if it's possible to use the mentioned plugins with them.

I wonder what domain class functionality you wish to get out of non-persistent classes?

Comment: Thanks but I think this is not going to work with the pluggins as they expect domain objects I guess.

Regarding the non-persistent domain objects is just for the remote ones (CRUD is managed using REST operations as I describe in my question)

Comment: So what plugins are you using and for what? Or you're not certain yet?

Comment: Not sure about the final decision but at least a search and security plugin. I'll try to make a quick test but I guess without domain objects won't work.